# dynamically change nginx proxy pass

Tags: nginx, dynamic, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

Hi i want to set a dynamic proxy pass in nginx. $myvar will take values such as ops/dev/qa etc. But when i validate the above nginx configuration file with nginx -t, i get "proxy_set_header" directive is not allowed here. Hope you can help me to identify the problem with this code.

```
location ~^/reporting-(?<myvar>[a-zA-Z]+) {

    if ($myvar = "ops") {


            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass          https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/reporting;
    }

            if ($myvar = "dev") {


            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass          https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8083/reporting;
    }



 }
```

Hi Thank You Timo. i am sure that this solution is fundamentally correct. But i'm still struggling with the url rewriting. in order to test this, i applied below code.

```
location /reporting-ops {

        proxy_set_header    Host $host;

        rewrite ^/reporting-ops/(.*) /reporting/$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.25:8931/reporting/$1;  #option 1

     #  proxy_pass http://192.168.1.25:8931/$1; # option 2

     }
```

But when i do this my browser url changes to /reporting like below. i think browser-url shouldn't change & the rewriting should happen when the request reach nginx.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to avoid if in this use case.
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Furthermore the `proxy_set_header` directive is NOT allowed in the context of `if`. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

I would use a `map` to to this

```sh
map $uri $upstream {
  ~^/reporting-dev/ 1.2.3.4:8080;
  ~^/reporting-qa/ 1.2.3.4:8081;
  default 1.2.3.4:8082;
}

server {

  location ~^/reporting-([a-zA-Z]+)/ {
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://$upstream/reporting;
  }
}
```

If you need to rewrite the `$uri` to pass anything "behind" reporting-aq|dev to the upstream do this.

```sh
map $ruri $upstream {
  ~^/reporting-dev/ 127.0.0.1:8080;
  ~^/reporting-qa/  127.0.0.1:8081;
}

server {
  #Keep the requested URI before! we rewrite it for the upstream
  set $ruri $uri;
  location / {
    return 200 "No match\n";
  }


  location ~ ^/reporting-([a-zA-Z]+)/ {
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     #rewrite the URI to get anything but reporting-qa|dev
     rewrite /reporting-([a-z]+)/(.*) /reporting/$2 break;
     proxy_pass http://$upstream;
  }
}


server {listen 8080; return 200 "OK DEV = $host$request_uri\n";}
server {listen 8081; return 200 "OK QA = $host$request_uri\n";}
```

Comment: Thank you for supporting. When i use the regular expression in the location block with the proxy pass inside i'm getting a message "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location give by regular expression ....

Comment: Have updated my answer. Did you need the `request_uri` without `reporting-qa` as part of the request to your upstream. Like /reporting-qa/some/ressource -> /reporting/some/resource?

Comment: Thank you again. yes i need to redirect /reporting-qa/some/resource to reporting/some/resource.

Comment: Then the second example (with the rewrite) will work for you. just tested it on my servers.

Comment: @TimoStark I have the same problem mention by **@Prageeth**. When I try http://x.x.x.x/reporting-ops/ in the 
browser I get redirected to http://x.x.x.x/reporting/login.html:jsessionid=D1....
How can I transparently send the request to http://x.x.x.x/reporting without altering the browser URL?

Comment: I have updated my answer. `proxy_redirect off;` should help here. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect